# Join two tables depending on date sequence

Tags: sql-server

In SQL Server 2008, I want to join two tables depending on date sequence. More specifically, I need to left join `Payments` table to `Profiles` table by the following rules:

1. `UserId` has to be matched.
2. Every record in `Payments` matches the record in `Profiles` with the closest `Profiles.CreationDate` before `Payments.PayDate`.

For a simplified example,

```
Table Payments:
UserId  PayDate Amount
1       2012    400
1       2010    500
2       2014    600

Table Profiles:
UserId  CreationDate Address
1       2009         NY
1       2015         MD
2       2007         NJ
2       2013         MA
3       2008         TX

Desired Result:
UserId  CreationDate PayDate Amount Address
1       2009         2010    500    NY
1       2009         2012    400    NY
2       2013         2014    600    MA
```

It's guaranteed that a user have at least 1 `Profiles` record before he pays. Another restriction is that I not authorized to write anything into the database.

I idea is first left join `Payments` with `Profiles`, then within the record group matching each `(UserId, PayDate)` tuple, sort it by `CreationDate`, then select the last record. But I don't know how to implement it in SQL language, or are there any better ways to do this merge?

Comment: this is a really bad database design... OUTER APPLY with TOP 1 record with ORDER BY DATEDIFF

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Outer Apply` to do this.

```
SELECT py.UserId,
       CreationDate,
       PayDate,
       Amount,
       Address
FROM   Payments py
       OUTER APPLY (SELECT TOP 1 *
                    FROM   Profiles pr
                    WHERE  py.UserId = pr.UserId
                    and    PayDate> CreationDate
                    ORDER  BY CreationDate desc) cs
```

[**SQLFIDDLE DEMO**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f4b29/18)